# Adding PictureBox.Image to a List of Bitmaps

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I have a List of Bitmaps and PictureBox. I want to add the PictureBox's Image to the List.
This code:

```
pictureBox1.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);
loadedImages.Add(new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image));
```

causes a NullReference Exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Tutorial_Picture_Viewer.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: If `loadedImages` is a `List<Bitmap>`  try: `loadedImages.Add( (Bitmap) pictureBox1.Image);`

Comment: `loadedImages` is, in fact, my `List<Bitmap>`. I tried your code and it gives the same error.

Comment: Did the PB actually load the image?

Comment: If I remove the `loadedImages.Add(...)` line, the PictureBox loads the image without a problem.

Comment: Did you initialize loadedImages ? It is better to show initialization code also so we don't have to guess.

Comment: If the picturebox has successfully load a bitmap it will work.  Here is the full code I would recommend : `if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK ) pictureBox1.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        if (pictureBox1.Image != null) loadedImages.Add((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image);` - Obviously you need to create the `OpenFileDialog `: `OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();` and just as obviously `List<Bitmap> loadedImages = new List<Bitmap>();`

Comment: Wait...you have to do that? Damn...I come from C++ and I didn't have to initialize lists there. Well, sorry for the stupid mistake and thanks for the help.

Comment: yup, List is an object and you create it. But you don't have to dispose ;-) - __That being said__ You __do__ need to dispose all those `Bitmaps`, one by one when you are done with them as they are GDI objects and as such among the __not__ managed things...! Welcome to the wonderful world of `c#` and `.NET, with their own set of wonders and pitfalls..!